# vim spelllang=en_us does not create ~/.vim/spell/en_us.utf-8.add

Tags: vim

I have `set spelllang=en_us` in my .vimrc.

When I add new words/names with `zg`, they are saved in ~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add.

Q1. How do I know I am using en_us for spell checking?

Q2. Is it supposed to save new words in ~/.vim/spell/en_us.utf-8.add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question:

You can issue the `:set spelllang?` command, this will echo the language (`en`) and region (`us`).

For the second question:

The [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27spellfile%27) states that normally one file is used for all regions, but you can add the region if you want to.